# Проверьте запятые

Tags: пунктуация

1.К настоящему времени они завершили сев кормовых культур, в том числе кукурузы- на площади 425 га, вместо планируемых 512 га. Правильно ли я расставила знаки препинания? У автора с обеих сторон запятыми выделялось выражение "на площади 425 га".
2.Уместно ли я поставила тире перед "и это": Поэтому полевые работы пришлось проводить в более жесткие сроки - и это при большой нагрузке на посевные агрегаты.

Comment: "425 га вместо планируемых 512 га". ===  Они что, недовыполнили план?

Comment: Да. Хозяйство убыточное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.К настоящему времени они завершили сев кормовых культур, в том числе кукурузы- на площади 425 га, вместо планируемых 512 га.

ВАРИАНТ:

*К настоящему времени они завершили сев кормовых культур; в том числе кукурузы -- на площади 425 га вместо планируемых 512 га.*

> 2. Уместно ли я поставила тире перед "и это"?

Я бы тоже тире поставил.

Answer (score 1):

1) К настоящему времени они завершили сев кормовых культур, в том числе кукурузы,  на площади 425 га вместо планируемых 512 га.

Пояснение:

а) в том числе кукурузы - обособленный оборот со значением включения;

б) вместо планируемых 512 га  - нераспространенный оборот в основном сообщении не обособляется.

Вообще говоря, обособление факультативное, зависит от распространенности, смысловой нагрузки, позиции в предложении, например: "Лекарь второпях, вместо двенадцати капель, налил целых  сорок".

2) Присоединительный оборот "и это..." обособляется с помощью тире или запятой (авторский выбор).

Comment: 425 га относится к кукурузе, а не к кормовым культурам, поэтому после кукурузы лучше поставить тире, а оборот "вместо планируемых 512 га"- пояснение

Comment: Из текста это неясно. Может быть, так: К настоящему времени они завершили сев кормовых культур (в том числе кукурузы на площади 425 га вместо планируемых 512 га). Или: К настоящему времени они завершили сев кормовых культур  - в том числе кукурузы на площади 425 га вместо планируемых 512 га.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения.